# Decoupling issue - improvements and alternatives

Tags: c#, asynchronous, json.net, solid-principles

I'm into learning SOLID principles - especially Inversion Of Control-DI-Decoupling, and as I'm reviewing one of my codes, I noticed that this one method (see below) gets my attention.

This code will be called by any methods that needs to read the json file,  accepts string values that will be used to lookup on a json file. But as you can see(I simplified the code - excluded the exception handling for the sake of this topic), I'm not sure where to start(there are a lot of initializations or dependencies?? happening and I'm not sure where to start).

Could this method/scenario a good candidate to start with? Which do you think should I retain? and needs to be decoupled?

Thanks.

```
public async Task<object> ReadJsonByKey(string jsonPath, string jsonKey)
{
    // First - is it okay to have an initialization at this stage?
    var value = new object();     

    // Second - is this fine to have this in the scope of this method?
    using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(jsonPath))  
    {
        // Third -  Calling Jobject that accepts new instance of JsonTextReader
        var jObject = await JObject.LoadAsync(new JsonTextReader(reader)); 
        obj = jObject.SelectToken(jsonKey);
    }
    return value;
}
```

The reason also I asked this is because (based from the standards ) loosely-coupled stuff can be easily tested - i.e, Unit Testing

```
[UnitTestSuite]
    [TestCase1]
        // Method should only be able to accept ".json" or ".txt" file

    [TestCase2]
        // JsonPath file is valid file system

    [TestCase3]
        // Method should be able to retrieve a node value based from a specific json and key

    [TestCase4]
        // Json-text file is not empty
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking? What exactly are you trying to de-couple this from?

Comment: @RagtimeWilly thanks for replying. Apologies if I didn't get this right, can we conclude that this method is already loosely coupled - safe to say that it can be used for unit testing easily - by passing a JSON Path & JSON Key and check for the validity of this method - module.

I will be needing to search things up more I guess on when can I call that it is already independent of the others.

Comment: It is not easy to unit-test because it depends on the file-system and each test will be an integration test which will test the method and the file-system

Comment: @SirRufo would you mind if can you guide me on how can we transform it to an easily testable method? Since there are a lot of things happening in that method, that's why I think it would best fit to use dependency injection-IOC on this one? or maybe not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to decouple an infrastructural concern from your application code.

Assuming that's the case you need a class which is responsible for reading the data:

```
public interface IDataReader
{
     Task<object> ReadJsonByKey(string jsonPath, string jsonKey)
}
```

The implementation of which would be your above code:

```
public class DataReader : IDataReader
{
    public async Task<object> ReadJsonByKey(string jsonPath, string jsonKey)
    {
        // First - is it okay to have an initialization at this stage?
        var value = new object();     

        // Second - is this fine to have this in the scope of this method?
        using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(jsonPath))  
        {
            // Third -  Calling Jobject that accepts new instance of JsonTextReader
            var jObject = await JObject.LoadAsync(new JsonTextReader(reader)); 
            obj = jObject.SelectToken(jsonKey);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

However this class is now doing both file reading & de-serialization so you could further separate into:

```
public class DataReader : IDataReader
{
    IDeserializer _deserializer;

    public DataReader(IDeserializer deserializer)
    {
        _deserializer = deserializer;
    }

    public async Task<object> ReadJsonByKey(string jsonPath, string jsonKey)
    {
        var json =  File.ReadAllText(jsonPath);

        return _deserializer.Deserialize(json, jsonKey);
    }
}
```

This would mean that could now unit test your `IDeserializer` independently of the file system dependency.

However, the main benefit should be that you can now mock the `IDataReader` implementation when unit testing your application code.

Comment: Awesome, I never thought that this could be decoupled even more, now I can test the deserialization and the reader without having to depend on a single - crowded method . Thank you so much. My votes don't get added to your answers since Im only 15 reputations below, apologies.

Comment: I can now work my way up to this, since this method is the "heart" of all transactions-processes in our system, it feeds on JSON source, so this method must be "right and tested carefully " in order for all processes to continue and work as expected.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

Make the function like:

`public async Task<object> ReadJsonByKey(TextReader reader, string jsonKey)`

Now the function works with any TextReader implementation, so you can pass a TextReader that reads from file or from memory or from any other data source.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that prevents you from unit-testing this properly is the `File` reference, which is a static. You won't be able to provide the method with a file, because it would have to physically exist. There are two ways you can go about solving this.

First, if it's possible, you could pass something else rather than a path to the method - a `FileStream` for example.

Second, arguably better, you would abstract the file system (I recommend using the [System.IO.Abstractions](https://github.com/System-IO-Abstractions/System.IO.Abstractions) and then the related TestingHelpers package) into a private field, pass the dependency via ctor injection.

```
private readonly IFileSystem fileSystem;

public MyClass(IFileSystem fileSystem)
{
    this.fileSystem = fileSystem;
}
```

And then in your method you'd use

```
fileSystem.File.OpenText(jsonPath);
```

This should allow you to unit-test this method with ease, by passing a `MockFileSystem` and creating a json file in-memory for the method to read. And unit-testability is actually a good indicator that your method is maintainable and has a well defined purpose - if you can test it easily with a not-so-complicated unit test, then it's probably good. If you can't, then it's definitely bad.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer this enlightened me on how things get independent to each other as much as possible., I will try to use this approach.

Comment: If this helped, consider accepting the answer so the question is "closed".